# Initialize a struct in C++ the C way

Tags: c++, c, struct, static, init

I initialize a static struct in C like that, but in C++ it doesn't want to compile. How do I get the equivalent in C++ that would still be compatible with C? (linux C code that I'm trying to compile on MSVC)

```
typedef struct float3 {
    float x,y,z;
} float3;

void main() {
    static float3 value = (float3){ 1.f, 5.f, 10.f };
}
```

MSVC (visual studio 2019) gives error at the opening bracket '{' after (float3).

```
Error (active)  E0029   expected an expression  cpptestvs   D:\Projects\cpptestvs\cpptestvs\cpptestvs.cpp   11
```

Comment: `static float3 value = { 1.f, 5.f, 10.f };`

Comment: There was no need for the *compound literal* syntax when a *designated initializer* would work just fine.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `void main()`   Although some compilers will allow other signatures for `main()`, per the c standard there are only two valid signatures: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *agrv[] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the cast to float3 in the statement enclosed inside `void main()`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> static float3 value = (float3){ 1.f, 5.f, 10.f };
> ```

This is a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), which is allowed in C but not C++. C allows you to create an unnamed object of the type `float3` and initialise it with an initializer-list. Some compilers, such as GCC, do support it as an extension but MSVC doesn't.

To do what you want you can do:

```
static float3 value = { 1.f, 5.f, 10.f };
```

This is [aggregate initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization): every non-static class member in the struct `float3` is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list. Your struct is an aggregate because it has no user-declared constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions.